# Select from mysql and format them with checkboxes and set checked="checked" attribute

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql tables named `facilities` and other one is `user_facilities`. In `facilities` table have stored all available facilities and `user_facilities` table have particular facilities belong to one user.

Now I need to fetch all the facilities from mysql and need to format with checkbox for each facility. While fetching every facilities I need to set `checked="checked"` attribute to checkboxes which are belong to current user.

I can select all facility from mysql like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name
        FROM cuisines";
```

And this is how it looks my `WHILE` loop.

```
$result = '';
// Fetch all the records:
while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    $result  = "<div class='checkbox'>\n";
    $result .= "    <label>\n";
    $result .= "        <input type='checkbox' name='facilities[]' value='{$id}'> {$name}\n";
    $result .= "    </label>\n";
    $result .= "</div>\n";

    $output[] = $result;    
}
```

Can anybody tell me how add 'checked="checked"` attribute for these checkboxes which are belong to current user?

This is my `user_facilities` table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_facilities(
    user_id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    facility_id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: How do you get the current user info? Is it stored in session?

Comment: `$result .= "        <input type='checkbox' checked = 'checked' name='facilities[]' value='{$id}'> {$name}\n";` based on condition check

Comment: You need to add a user_id column to the cuisines table. Then, you can compare the user_id from your session with that id. If it matches, you check the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

if you will have one **facility_id** for **user_id** in your **user_facilities**

```
$output = array();
// Fetch all the records:
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $check="";
    if($facility_id == $cuisines_id){ $check = "checked='checked'"}
    $result  = "<div class='checkbox'>\n";
    $result .= "    <label>\n";
    $result .= "        <input type='checkbox' name='facilities[]' value='{$id}' ".$chec."> {$name}\n";
    $result .= "    </label>\n";
    $result .= "</div>\n";

    $output[] = $result;    
}
```

Let's say you have multiple facility_id for a user.

```
$facility_id=array(1,2,3,4,5);

foreach($facility_id as $facilites)
{
    $check="";
    if($facilites == $cuisines_id){ $check = "checked='checked'"}
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='facilities[]' value='{$id}' ".$chec."> {$name}\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. but I have more facilities for one user. Thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Get current user id, get facilities $id's that belongs to current user.

Make IF inside your While loop and

```
if($faicilitityId == $id) {
 $result  = "<div class='checkbox' checked='checked'>\n";
 } esle {
 $result  = "<div class='checkbox'>\n";
}
```